# Asynquence step that waits for all steps to succeed or fail

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a server-side Node.JS script that handles file uploads by (1) saving the upload to a specific location and (2) recording it in a DB. I have been using the Asynquence library and its gate function (equivalent to Promise.all) to perform these steps in parallel, but I need the sequence to behave so that if either step fails, I undo the other step if it succeeded. Obviously the undoing steps can only execute if its matching step has already succeeded (i.e removing the file or db record)

Gate doesn't seem to work for this case since it fires the error handler if any of the steps fail. Is there a function that waits for all steps to either succeed or fail?

Comment: Performance aside, you will find it simpler to do the two stages in sequence. Thus, if the first stage fails, nothing needs to be undone; if the second stage fails, only the first stage needs to be undone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think of `catch` as an asynchronous counterpart to `try`, then you can build a quick wrapper that wraps every value passed to `gate` or `Promise.all` and returns a "succeeded" or "failed" result.

```
function waitForAll(inputArray) {
  // Return Promise.all on an array where for each array value...
  return Promise.all(inputArray.map(function(x) 
    // ...we wrap it in a tiny dict with the semantics we want.
    return Promise.resolve(x).then(function(value) {
      return { success: true, value: value };
    }, function(error) {
      return { success: false, error: error };
    });
  }));
}
```

As a bonus, since you can take any action per-promise in your wrapper, you can even report failure quickly through a separate channel, or start cancelling or rolling back successful actions as soon as any asynchronous step fails.